# RestKit non-kvc object mapping

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I am experimenting with integrating RestKit into my current project.
I am retrieving data with the format:

```
[
    {"id":"1",
    "name":"john"}
    {"id":"2",
    "name":"bob"}
]
```

Following the excellent tutorial in the [RestKit wiki](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping), I see that the recommended, fully KVC-compliant format would be:

```
{"customers": [
    {"id":"1",
    "name":"john"}
    {"id":"2",
    "name":"bob"} ]
}
```

Then I could use

```
[mappingProvider setMapping:customerMapping forKeyPath:@"customers"];
```

Unfortunately, I do not at the moment have control over the data format on the server.

Later in the RestKit wiki, there is a section that solves my problem: "Mapping without KVC." I would associate the objectMapping with the objects at load-time.

```
[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/data" objectMapping:customerMapping delegate:self];
```

Here's my problem: The wiki is for 0.9.3. But **this method is deprecated in 0.10.1**. Yes, it still works - for now.

If this method is being deprecated, and keeping in mind that I don't control the data, what is the appropriate way to assign an object mapping to a class in this sort of non-KVC situation?

Comment: Somebody here may have an excellent answer for you, but while you wait, I suggest searching on / post to the RestKit dev group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/restkit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not positive about this but I believe it is deprecated in support of blocks... this might work:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/data" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader* loader) {
    [loader setObjectMapping:customerMapping];
}];
```

And, naturally, use the block to replace the delegate methods.

Comment: Good Point! I was finding this.

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed what I was looking for. I need to get more used to using blocks...

Comment: Well, but in 0.20.0 version, how can we do this?