# Web API C# - Returning full KVC Json

Tags: c#, json, restkit, asp.net-web-api

I am using RestKit from an iOS app to connect to a Web API service that we are building in C# .Net 4.

I am having the same issue from here: [RestKit non-kvc object mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007784/restkit-non-kvc-object-mapping)

Basically C# returns something like:

formatted raw
BODY

```
[
{
 "Id":6,
 "Guid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
 "Owner":null,
 "Message":"Testing Wom#10",
 "HashTags":null,
 "createdtime":"2012-10-28T00:00:00",
 "PlayedCount":100,
 "DurationInSecs":150.0,
 "FileSizeInBytes":20000,
 "FileUrl":"http://www.wom.com"
}
]
```

While the standard format expected by RestKit is

```
{"woms": [
{
 "Id":6,
 "Guid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
 "Owner":null,
 "Message":"Testing Wom#10",
 "HashTags":null,
 "createdtime":"2012-10-28T00:00:00",
 "PlayedCount":100,
 "DurationInSecs":150.0,
 "FileSizeInBytes":20000,
 "FileUrl":"http://www.wom.com"
}
]
```

I don't care using a way or another, however, it seems that it would be easier from the iOS side to make C# return the "customers" class name.

How can I tell C# to return that?

Thanks.

This is the current code in my ApiController in C#:

```
namespace WomWeb.Controllers.Apis
{
[Authorize]
public class WomsController : ApiController
{
    private WomContext db = new WomContext();

    // GET api/Woms
    public IEnumerable<Wom> GetWoms()
    {
        return db.Woms.AsEnumerable();            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had some issues like this when trying to serialize JSON in C#. I think the easiest way is  wrap the customer in another class. If you only need to serialize in one place you can do something like `var temp = new Object { customer customer = new customer(); }` right before making the call to serialize it.

Comment: Thanks. In order to do that I would have to change the return type of the ApiController Method. I do not think this would work out in my case. I have updated the question to post some relevant code. Thanks again.

Comment: This line `return db.Woms.AsEnumerable();` returns the json displayed at top? I'm very doubtful of that. The code posted doesn't show where the json is deserialized. That's the point where you wrap it in another object. Of course another approach is to do `json = @"{"customers":" + json + "}"` (may need escapes on the inner quotes). Which you can do anywhere once it's a string.

Comment: Evan, I have updated the question to include the actual copy/paste of the result of my web service. The json serialization is done automatically by the C# Web API. There should be some sort of decorator or setting to make it include the class name, but, yes, AsEnumerable() results in the json at the top. Regards.

Comment: BTW: this is a sample of the Web API technologies: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api. Pretty powerful stuff in my opinion.

Comment: That abstraction is fairly impressive. I would just wrap it earlier on. Make a class `Wom` which contains one member - `public wom woms;` It's kind of annoying because it requires you to have one more level of indirection but it works and from what I know, it's the only way to make it work.

Comment: Yeah... I haven't found a solution. This link explains how to customize the json serializer: http://tostring.it/2012/07/18/customize-json-result-in-web-api/. It doesn't resolve my issue, but explains.

Comment: well... at least I found a way to not create another class. See my answer here using an anonymous class.

Comment: @rufo Yeah that was my original suggestion... I guess I didn't need to `Object` thing but I didn't remember the syntax exactly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I have found so far. Basically replace the IEnumerable by HttpResponseMessage and use the Request.CreateResponse to respond (code below).

While it works it is less than ideal: I lose the abstraction, and now the controller respond with Json regardless of the request headers (that logic was resolved automatically, but when using the CreateResponse I am writing directly to the output).

```
// GET api/Woms           
//public IEnumerable<Wom> GetWoms()
public HttpResponseMessage GetWoms()
{
  //return  db.Woms.Include("Owner").AsEnumerable(); 
  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { woms = Include("Owner").AsEnumerable() });
}
```